# Using a external websocket api inside my application websockets

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to use a external websockets reference inside my applications websocket, but I am not able to get it work properly. I'm very new to Node in general, so I'm sure I'm making some noob mistake.

io is my internal websocket instance wired up to my application. bws is a external websocket API. When my application client side sends a message on the 'ticker' channel. I would like for bws to utilize this string setup a subscription and send the msg back through my internal io socket.

pair is a string : 'BTCUSD'

ticker : JSON object { 'BID': 1, 'ASK': 2} etc..

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
const path = require('path');
const BFX = require('bitfinex-api-node')
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();
server.listen(80);
const bws = new BFX(API_KEY, API_SECRET, opts).ws

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log('socket connected');


    bws.on('ticker', (pair, ticker) => {
        var now = new Date;
        client.set(pair + '-' + getFormattedDate(), JSON.stringify(ticker), redis.print);
        socket.emit('ticker', {
            pair: pair,
            ticker: ticker
        });
    });

    socket.on('ticker', function (msg) {
        bws.on('open', () => {
            bws.subscribeTicker(msg)
            /*  bws.subscribeOrderBook('BTCUSD')
              bws.subscribeTrades('BTCUSD')*/
        })
    });

});
```

Doh I figured it out

```
var bwsOpen = false;
 socket.on('ticker', function (msg) {
        bws.on('open', () => {
            bwsOpen = true;
        })
    });

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log('socket connected');


    bws.on('ticker', (pair, ticker) => {
        var now = new Date;
        client.set(pair + '-' + getFormattedDate(), JSON.stringify(ticker), redis.print);
        socket.emit('ticker', {
            pair: pair,
            ticker: ticker
        });
    });

    socket.on('ticker', function (msg) {
       if(bwsOpen) {
        bws.subscribeTicker(msg);
       }
    });

});
```

Comment: This phrase "trying to use a external websockets reference inside my applications websocket" is not obvious to me what that means.  Please explain.  Also, in  your code what is a `ticker` and what is a `pair`?  You cannot send a webSocket socket object over a webSocket connection if that's what you're asking.  That object only applies to one specific host (the one it was created on).  So, if that's what you're trying to do, you can't do that.  Now, if you back up and describe the overall problem you're trying to solve, we can probably help you find a different way to do it.

Comment: please see my update description.

pair = 'BTCUSD'
ticker = JSON object { "Ask": 1, "Bid":2 etc }

Comment: So, you have an incoming message over the bws webSocket and you just want to send that message out over your other webSocket?  Is that what you're asking?  I see you have code to attempt to do something like that already.  What is the specific problem you want us to help with?

Comment: If you have multiple socket.io connections to your server and you want them to all have their own state, then that looks like a problem for how you're sharing the `bws` connection because you only have one of those and one set of subscriptions. So, `bws` will notify all ticker subscriptions to every socket.io client connection, even though a given socket.io connection didn't ask for that ticker. In other words, bws has the union of all subscriptions and you're sending all of those to every socket.io connection. That part seems wrong. I'm still unsure what question you're asking for help with.

Comment: Thanks  I figured it out. However to answer you question. bws does  share state. So appears also like i need to unsubscribe before submitting a new subscription.

Comment: Just unsubscribing before submitting a new subscription won't work properly.  You need the ability for multiple different clients to be able to subscribe to multiple different things.